# Does QTimer resuse unique id?

Tags: qt, timer, qt4.8

I looked in the documentation and I didn't find something about reusing unique Id.

The documentation says about the startTimer function:

```
The function returns a unique integer timer ID
```

But how long will it be unique? Does it reuse the ids at some point?

Comment: I was able to trace all the way down to qabstracteventdispatcher.cpp/.h under src/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel for Qt 5.2.  The top of that file sets up the parameters and then you can take peek at QAbstractEventDispatcherPrivate::allocateTimerId().

Comment: According to [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#alternatives-to-qtimer) there is exist ability to create the number of timers that equal to number of timers that operating system able provide.

Answer (score 0):

> But how long will it be unique?

The timer ID should remain unique until it is released via QAbstractEventDispatcherPrivate::releaseTimerId();

In other words, calling killTimer().

> Does it reuse the ids at some point?

I quickly wrote a simple test to see if the timer ID would get reused:

Something.h:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGlobal>

class Something : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Something() : QObject() {}
  ~Something() {}

};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Something.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  Something thing;

  int i = thing.startTimer(1000);
  qDebug() << i;

  thing.killTimer(i);

  i = thing.startTimer(1000);
  qDebug() << i;

  return a.exec();
}
```

The result:

```
1
1
```

Finally, using QTimer exclusively... you can test with:

```
class Something : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Something() : QObject(), timer(NULL) {}
  ~Something() {}

  void runme() 
  {

    timer = new QTimer();
    // Old school ;)
    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerEvent()));
    timer->start(100);
  }

public Q_SLOTS:

  void timerEvent()
  {
    qDebug() << timer->timerId();
    timer->stop();

    delete timer;
    timer = new QTimer();
    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerEvent()));
    timer->start(1000);

  }

public:
  QTimer* timer;
};
```

Then just kick it off and run it:

```
  Something thing;
  thing.runme();
```

Comment: Rather use `timer->deleteLater()` than deleting outright, the `QTimer::timeout()` signal is still being executed.

Comment: When I do as you (start/kill/start), I got the ids 654311482 and 687865914.